# Extremely strong QRM on VHF?

Tags: vhf, noise

I don't usually operate in 2 m, save for FM satellites. I usually go to a nearby park when I do this, for better view of the horizon. But I tried working them from home for the past couple of days, and found there is massive QRM around 145.650 MHz. So strong, I can hear it on my handheld with the antenna detached. It sounds like a motor.

With the SDR, with no antenna attached and the input gain set to zero, I see it at -45 with a noise floor of -60. The signal looks like a hump with the sides wobbling left to right (as if you were rocking a glass of water on a table). Yesterday, it looked like this:

[image]

This QRM appears all around the neighborhood. It's difficult to pinpoint since it's so strong (it's so strong I don't need to open my squelch to hear it).

The signal stays mostly at 145.650 but from time to time it shifts up and down. Yesterday it was at 145.850.

What on earth could be causing such strong interference? Could it be power line related?

Power here is 220 V 50 Hz. Overhead 220 V wires and buried 13.2 kV lines. On HF I have the usual S7 to S9 city noise.

I was able to take a screen capture of SDRsharp during the two "moments" the noise has.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THyrpk0yXGI

Comment: The sides are almost certainly artifacts of clipping / nonlinearity due to the signal being very in your receiver. How much better do things get when you disable the squelch of your handheld, and put it in a metal box? Assuming you don't have a lot of these standing around, alternatively go to the basement. (no, a microwave oven typically won't work well; these things are mainly RF-"proof" for their 2.4 GHz operating frequency only) If that is significantly quieter, try with your SDR down there: This would look like a very slow digital mode, probably BPSK with a very tight pulse shaping filter

Comment: Maybe you should use fox hunting techniques to discover the origin of the signal.

Comment: Is it just a carrier (i.e., just quiet?)  Cable TV leaks will cause those.  If you're lucky and can find a tech for the company who (a) knows what you're talking about and (b) cares (and good luck finding one), you can get that fixed.

Comment: @rclocher3 the problem is that the signal is so strong, I can hear it without an antenna.

Comment: @Duston i dont think it is. It shifts frequencies up and down from time to time. If it was a channel carrier it would stay in the same place.

Comment: @hjf an [offset attenuator](http://www.homingin.com/joek0ov/offatten.html) works well on very strong signals, and is quite inexpensive.  Maybe a fox hunter near you already has one and wouldn't mind helping.

Comment: Try putting a 50 Ohm terminator on the antenna input.  Have you considered that this signal might be generated by your radio or it's power supply?  If not, try fox hunting by driving around your neighborhood/town/city to see how far the signal goes before it disappears.

Comment: @hotpaw2 the noise appears on 3 different radios: a RTL SDR, a Baofeng, and a Yaesu FT60.

Comment: What's the oscillation period left to right ('glass of water' analogy)?

Comment: @user124039 about 1sec, maybe a little less. I'll try making a screenshot tonight

Comment: @user124039 I added a video to the question, see youtube link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THyrpk0yXGI